# Nested Modals Zoom/Blurring. Issue with Closing Modals

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add some functionality to this setup.
As you will see, it is an attempt to make a nested modal setup, that on every click on a modal link, it recedes and blurs everything behind the modal.

I have managed to make it work, but I am trying to do two things:

1. Make everything fade in and fade out. As of now, the background blurs and recedes slowly, but I would like to control the speed of the modal opening/closing.
2. make the ESC key close the modals. This is proven difficult, as they are nested.

Thanks all

HTML

```
<div id="content">
 <div class="container">
         <a href="#myModal1" class="modal-button">Modal</a>
     </div>
  </div>
 <div id="myModal1" class="modal">
   <div class="modal-container">
       <header><h2>Modal</h2><span class="close">×</span></header>
       <div class="content">
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
          <a href="#myModal2" class="modal-button">
         This is a nested modal link.</a>
         </p>
       </div>
     </div>
 </div>
 <div id="myModal2" class="modal">
   <div class="modal-container">
       <header><h2>Nested Modal</h2><span class="close">×</span></header>
       <div class="content">
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
          <a href="#myModal" class="modal-button">
         This is a nested modal link.</a>
         </p>
       </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
.container {width: 80%;margin: auto;padding-top:40px; font-size: 2vw;}
#content { position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width: 100%; height:100%; overflow:auto;}

.modal { box-sizing: border-box; display: none; position: fixed; z-index: 1; padding-top: 3.125rem; left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: auto; transition: all 1.0s ease; }

.modal-container{-ms-box-orient: vertical; display: -ms-flex; display: -webkit-flex; display: flex; -ms-flex-direction: column; -webkit-flex-direction: column; flex-direction: column;font-size: 2vw;}

/* The Close Button */
.close {float:right; font-size: 4vw;padding-right: 10px; transition: all 1.0s ease;}
.close:hover, .close:focus { color: lightgrey; text-decoration: none; cursor: pointer; }
/* Modal Content */
header, .content, footer {width: 80%;margin:auto;}
header.image, .contentImage, footer.image {width: 100%;margin:auto;}
.content {background: none; -ms-flex: 1 1 auto; -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto; flex: 1 1 auto; overflow: auto; min-height: 0; height: 80vh;}

.open { overflow: hidden; }
.open>* { -webkit-filter: blur(5px); filter: blur(5px); transform: scale(0.9); transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;}
.modal { -webkit-filter: blur(0px); filter: blur(0px); transform: scale(0.9); transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;}
.modal .open { -webkit-filter: blur(5px); filter: blur(5px); transform: scale(0.9); transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;}
```

JS

```
$(function () {
  const openModals = [];
  $('a.modal-button').click(e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(e.target).closest('.modal').add('body').addClass('open');
    openModals.push($($(e.target).attr('href')).fadeIn());
  });
  $(window).add('.close').click(e => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if ($(e.target).is('.modal, .close')) {
      const closing = openModals.pop().addClass('modal-content-active');
      setTimeout(() => {closing.hide().removeClass('modal-content-active')}, 0);
      if (openModals.length > 0) {
        openModals[openModals.length - 1].removeClass('open');
      } else $('body').removeClass('open');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: What do you mean "control the speed of the modal opening/closing"? You could transition the scale of the element just like you've transitioned the filters.  
And for an idea on how I would approach multiple modals, I would probably use a manager with a stack. Whenever a modal is opened, add it to the stack. Whenever a modal is closed or escape is pressed, pop it.

Comment: demo: https://codepen.io/3igdw94y/pen/dybxwXg